# Recovering Grub

Tags: partitioning, grub2, gparted

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub)

Are there some resources that could help me recover from Grub2 problems?

I installed Ubuntu 10.10 and Windows 7 on my hard disk.   I had Grub2 as the bootloader for both of them.
Problems with my BIOS and hard disk caused me to lose my Grub settings.
My previous Linux installation was on the sda5 partition, and I want to be able to recover the grub configuration for it.