# How do i install Windows 7 on separate hdd and ubuntu on a separate drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive, windows-7

I just acquired a new ssd such that  don't have to use inventor through some virtual machine with windows on my ubuntu, but the problem is,  how do i easily  install windows on my second hard drive, and still have the option to dual boot between ubuntu and windows?

I read some post regarding this, and all them states that both of them have issues with the boot loaders, which i don't see should be a problem here as the OS's are being installed on separate drives.

My current OS is ubuntu, which is installed on my primary SSD. 
The other one is empty => actually not at the moment, but yeah after I format it, it should be empty.

Can I somehow from ubuntu (my primary ssd) install Windows onto my second hard drive? if so how? and what about the boot loader, is it possible to add some form boot loading option, such that i can decide whether i want to boot from windows or ubuntu?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS, system and is Ubuntu in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? Windows 7 DVD is BIOS and must be copied to flash drive and files moved to make UEFI bootable. Easiest to disconnect Ubuntu drive and install. If not disconnected make sure BIOS is set to boot new Windows drive by default. In BIOS mode it will put its 100MB boot partition on BIOS boot drive and just overwrite first 100MB of your Ubuntu. Once installed and both drives connected run this: `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Windows after ubuntu on a separate HDD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/57298/installing-windows-after-ubuntu-on-a-separate-hdd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I had two problems.

1. NEVER use any Kingston related (in this case HyperX) USB drives for boot loading..  That won't work.
2. I didn't use ? `grub` as it didn't detect windows. Instead i installed `grub` , which with an `sudo update-grub2` were able to find Win7.

Besides that and the multiple driver i had to find and install, everything worked out.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

You will install the windows 7 on the second hard disk.

You will configure your bios to use the first hard disk that has ubuntu for boot priority. (or make slave the second hdd (windows) and master disk the disk with ubuntu, that will work too)

Next you will configure grub, (if you don't have grub install it) and add the windows 7 hdd/+partition.

That would be my solution